# Implementing task primitives based on asio::awaitable

Tags: c++, boost-asio, c++20, coroutine, asio

I'm looking for a way to implement task primitives like `whenAll`, `whenAny`, `taskFromResult` on top of (boost) asios `awaitable<T>` coroutine type.

What I've got so far is a function that creates an `awaitable<T>` from a completion callback. However I'm unsure how I'm supposed to run multiple tasks in parallel on the specified `io_context` and await all of them or until any one of them is finished.

In .NET there are primitives like `Task.WhenAny`, `Task.WhenAll` and types like `TaskCompletionSource` that make it easy to work with tasks. Did anyone do this for asio based coroutines?

Comment: I showed what Asio currently has. Also look at https://github.com/lewissbaker/cppcoro#taskt for these concepts without Asio

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the experimental operator overloads to combine awaitables.

E.g.

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8f14d6ab5c0eb886)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/awaitable.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/detached.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/experimental/awaitable_operators.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/use_awaitable.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
auto now = std::chrono::steady_clock::now;
static auto start = now();

using namespace boost::asio::experimental::awaitable_operators;
using boost::asio::awaitable;
using boost::asio::use_awaitable;
using boost::system::error_code;


awaitable<void> foo_and() {
    boost::asio::steady_timer tim1(co_await boost::asio::this_coro::executor, 1s);
    boost::asio::steady_timer tim2(co_await boost::asio::this_coro::executor, 2s);

    co_await (tim1.async_wait(use_awaitable) && tim2.async_wait(use_awaitable));
}

awaitable<void> foo_or() {
    boost::asio::steady_timer tim1(co_await boost::asio::this_coro::executor, 1s);
    boost::asio::steady_timer tim2(co_await boost::asio::this_coro::executor, 2s);

    co_await (tim1.async_wait(use_awaitable) || tim2.async_wait(use_awaitable));
}

int main() {
    boost::asio::io_context ioc;

    auto handler = [](auto caption) {
        return [=](std::exception_ptr e) {
            try {
                if (e)
                    std::rethrow_exception(e);
                std::cout << caption << " succeeded at ";
            } catch (std::exception const& e) {
                std::cout << caption << " failed at ";
            }
                std::cout  << (now() - start) / 1.0s << "s" << std::endl;
        };
    };

    co_spawn(ioc.get_executor(), foo_and(), handler("foo_and"));
    co_spawn(ioc.get_executor(), foo_or(), handler("foo_or"));

    ioc.run();
}
```

Prints e.g.

```
foo_or succeeded at 1.00153s
foo_and succeeded at 2.00106s
```

### BONUS

With some more C++17 and default completion tokens:

```
awaitable<void> foo_and(auto... delays) {
    auto ex = co_await boost::asio::this_coro::executor;

    co_await(Timer(ex, delays).async_wait() && ...);
}

awaitable<void> foo_or(auto... delays) {
    auto ex = co_await boost::asio::this_coro::executor;

    co_await(Timer(ex, delays).async_wait() || ...);
}
```

Now you can supply variadic lists of delays:

```
co_spawn(ioc.get_executor(), foo_and(100ms, 1500ms, 75ms), handler("foo_and"));
co_spawn(ioc.get_executor(), foo_or(1s, 5min, 65ms), handler("foo_or"));
```

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d81fba8cb286055c)**:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/awaitable.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/detached.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/experimental/awaitable_operators.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/use_awaitable.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
auto now = std::chrono::steady_clock::now;
static auto start = now();

using namespace boost::asio::experimental::awaitable_operators;
using boost::asio::awaitable;
using boost::asio::use_awaitable;
using boost::system::error_code;

using Timer = boost::asio::use_awaitable_t<>::as_default_on_t<boost::asio::steady_timer>;

awaitable<void> foo_and(auto... delays) {
    auto ex = co_await boost::asio::this_coro::executor;

    co_await(Timer(ex, delays).async_wait() && ...);
}

awaitable<void> foo_or(auto... delays) {
    auto ex = co_await boost::asio::this_coro::executor;

    co_await(Timer(ex, delays).async_wait() || ...);
}

int main() {
    boost::asio::io_context ioc;

    auto handler = [](auto caption) {
        return [=](std::exception_ptr e) {
            try {
                if (e)
                    std::rethrow_exception(e);
                std::cout << caption << " succeeded at ";
            } catch (std::exception const& e) {
                std::cout << caption << " failed at ";
            }
                std::cout  << (now() - start) / 1ms << "ms" << std::endl;
        };
    };

    co_spawn(ioc.get_executor(), foo_and(100ms, 1500ms, 75ms), handler("foo_and"));
    co_spawn(ioc.get_executor(), foo_or(1s, 5min, 65ms), handler("foo_or"));

    ioc.run();
}
```

Prints e.g.

```
foo_or succeeded at 65ms
foo_and succeeded at 1500ms
```

Comment: Added a bonus take with defaulted completion tokens and fold expressions.